# create user session after 5 min's inactivity

Tags: sql, hive

Using SQL, how can I create a new session if the user has been inactive for 5 minutes?

```
userid           timestamp          session
1                10:15            1_10:15
1                10:16            1_10:15
1                10:17            1_10:15
1                10:23            1_10:23
2                10:18            2_10:18
2                10:18            2_10:18
2                10:19            2_10:18
2                10:30            2_10:30
```

I have tried using lead and taking the difference between current and lead, but it is not giving the correct result.

```
e.g. lead(timestamp,1) over(partition by userid order by timestamp asc) as leadTime,
```

can someone plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `LAG` function to define a flag=1 where current row time is greater than the previous row time by more than 5 minutes, then use a cumulative sum window function (on that flag) to create unique groups for the consecutive rows that have time difference less than 5 minutes.

```
with get_groups as
(
  select userid, timestamp, SUM(flag) over (partition by userid order by timestamp) grp
  from
  (
    select *,
       case 
        when unix_timestamp(timestamp) - unix_timestamp(lag(timestamp) over (partition by userid order by timestamp)) >300
        then 1 else 0
       end as flag
    from table_name
  ) T
)

select userid, timestamp, 
       CONCAT(userid, '_', MIN(timestamp) over (partition by userid, grp)) as session
from get_groups
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0Wu7pWAn) on MySQL. I'm not sure if this is a valid Hive syntax, but you may consider the idea of this solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ahmed. your query worked in hive also.